# Layout compatible to different display size/orientation in Metro XAML app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

What are the principles of supporting different display size/modes/orientations in Metro/Winstore app using XAML/C# ? Are there guidelines?

At the moment I want to be able to display a list view with 2 tiles in portrait mode and 5 tiles in landscape. **I want these 2/5 tiles to fill the screen width automatically on the mode change.**

**Shall I just bind witdth of the tile template to a property and calculate it manually or is there more elegant tools in the .NET 4.5 ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward solution would be to use a `BasicPage` template that uses a `LayoutAwarePage` base class and provides a visual state for each `ApplicationViewState` (`FullScreenLandscape, Filled, Snapped, FullScreenPortrait`). Then define two designs and use visual states to switch between the designs. You could handle `Window.Current.SizeChanged` events to update the dimensions to make the tiles be exactly the portion of screen size, but that would be counterproductive and might not actually be the best design since users might not immediately see that the content is scrollable and you would also need to resize fonts, images, etc. to fit the new size. You could put these in a `Viewbox` control too if you really want to map your content dimensions to screen size.